# Using make to pack files in directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In existing project I am packing files using `make`.
I am trying to rewrite make, so it does not have to clear everything on every my change. I have targets like this:

```
device1pack1.pack: images/device1/pack1/*.png packer
    packer -o device1pack1.pack -i images/device1/pack1/*.png
```

problem is, images are not getting changed. I just put some images inside or delete them, so their modification date usually old, so make target does not getting rebuild. Only thing changing is modification date of `images/device1/pack1`. But that is directory. How do I make it so when I delete or put a file into it make will think this is outdated target and rebuild it?

P.S. I have a lot such targets (around 800) and about 30 folders with images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the directory as a prerequisite.  Then any time the directory time-last-modified changes (which will happen every time you add, remove, or rename a file in the directory) the target will be run.

Comment: Oh, now I feel just a little stupid. For some reason it told me 'No rule to make target ...', but now it seems to be working fine. Thank you!

Comment: It will tell you "no rule to make target" if the directory does not exist... since make has no idea how to create it.  Or if you mistyped it :-)